# How do I replace a default graphic in a `beamer` theme with one of my own choosing?

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am using an own beamer theme beamerthemeXY.sty which includes a (blue) graphic bow.eps. This graphic is in

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/themes/images
```

and is known by the latex system.It is included in the theme by

```
\includegraphics[width=1.01\paperwidth]{bow}.
```

Is it possible to replace this picture for my slides by a local (e.g. orange) picture? If I delete the picture from the images-directory, make texhash and then write

```
\graphicspath{{./img/}}
```

in my document, the local (orange) graphics ./img/bow.eps is used. But only if there is no bow.eps in the directory texlive.../images.

The file beamerthemeXY.sty

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: beamerthemeXY.sty,v 1.0 2014/04/01 $
\RequirePackage{graphics}
\mode<presentation>
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{XY}{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.17\paperheight]{}
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
      \put(0, 7){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{bow}}
    \end{picture}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}%
\mode<all>
```

The file main.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{XY}
  \graphicspath{{./img/}}
}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}{Another frame}
  \includegraphics{img/bow}
  \par\bigskip
  \includegraphics{bow}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The file bow.eps in blue and in orange and a Makefile for Fedora Linux are included in the archive

```
http://www.informatik.uni-oldenburg.de/~sos/example.zip
```

While making the example files I observed the same behaviour without installing the theme: The graphicspath is only used if the file bow.eps is not found (renamed) in the local directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Another ansatz

this simply uses `\pgfdeclareimage` which can easily be overwritten in your local `.tex` file (this is probably simpler than my other answer, but playing with nearly infinite possibilities to choose the colour was so much fun :)

beamerthemeXY.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: beamerthemeXY.sty,v 1.0 2014/04/01 $

\mode<presentation>

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{headimg}{bow}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{XY}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.17\paperheight]{}
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
      \put(0, 7){\pgfuseimage{headimg}}
    \end{picture}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}%
\mode<all>
```

main.tex:

```
% Time-stamp: <2014-04-02 13:14:29 ewi>
%
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{XY}
  \graphicspath{{./img/}}
}

% choose whatever image you want 
% if none is choosen the default image will be displayed
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{headimg}{./img/bow}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\begin{frame}{Another frame}
  \includegraphics{img/bow}
  \par\bigskip
  \includegraphics{bow}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

So to summarize your question, you basically want to invert the order in which the different locations are searched?

Sounds difficult ...

### Suggestion

Including the image as a `tikzpicture` and change the colour individually in your .tex file.

beamerthemeXY.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header: beamerthemeXY.sty,v 1.0 2014/04/01 $
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\mode<presentation>

    \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,90,165}

    \defbeamertemplate*{headline}{XY}{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0.17\paperheight]{}
        \begin{picture}(0,0)
            \put(-5,0){
                \begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.20pt, x=0.20pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
                    \path[fill=mycolor] (0.0000,139.5590) -- (0.0000,0.0000) -- (960.0000,0.0000) -- (1920.0000,0.0000) -- (1920.0000,81.0000) -- (1920.0000,162.0000) -- (1851.7500,162.0070) .. controls (1779.9566,162.0150) and (1645.4583,163.2782) .. (1534.5000,164.9872) .. controls (860.4472,175.3697) and (366.1651,207.9400) .. (85.0000,260.5011) .. controls (61.8651,264.8260) and (2.3947,277.6381) .. (0.7572,278.6501) .. controls (0.3407,278.9074) and (0.0000,216.3165) .. (0.0000,139.5590) -- cycle;
                \end{tikzpicture}
            }
        \end{picture}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    }%

\mode<all>
```

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{XY}
  \graphicspath{{./img/}}
}

% change to whatever colour you want
% if you don't define a new colour, the default blue will be used
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,200,165}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Another frame}
         test
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

### For fun

You can even change the colour for individual slides

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
  \usetheme{XY}
  \graphicspath{{./img/}}
}

% change to whatever colour you want
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,200,165}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{Another frame}
         test
    \end{frame}

    \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,0,165}
    \begin{frame}{Another frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

    \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{0,200,0}
    \begin{frame}{Another frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

    \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{200,0,0}
    \begin{frame}{Another frame}
        test
    \end{frame}         

    \definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{200,200,165}
    \begin{frame}{Another frame}
        test
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, I want to invert the order. If I put a modified copy of a style-file into my working-directory, it is used. But if I put a modified picture there, it is not used. The command 'graphicspath' does not work as I would expect. The workarounds are not what I need since I shall use the theme with pictures in many different colors and so I would need many themes for that, only changing the name of the image. So I think the only solution is to not provide a default image. That's a pity. If I delete the default image everything works fine but everyone must provide his own image(s).